# Material UI: How to change font size of label in React Material Ui Stepper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

In React material ui, I want to change font size of stepper label. How to acheive that?

```
  function getSteps() {
    return [
      "OPTION 1",
      "OPTION 2",
      "OPTION 3"
      "OPTION 4"
     
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a custom css to your webpage :

```
.MuiStepLabel-labelContainer span {
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

You can adjust to your desired font size by changing the "font-size" value.

Comment: i didnt get it...can you explain

Comment: You could just apply this css into your css file to alter the stepper label's font size.

Material UI will generate the stepper label with the ".MuiStepLabel-labelContainer" class. The mentioned custom css will override the default font-size.

Answer (score 2):

Target the `label` CSS rule name in the `classes` prop

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: "24px"
  }
});

function App () {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <StepLabel classes={{label: classes.customLabelStyle}}>
  );
}
```